# Splash screen still exist in next activity android

Tags: java, android

I created a splash screen due to this tutorial: [Splash Screen right way](https://android.jlelse.eu/launch-screen-in-android-the-right-way-aca7e8c31f52)

But I have a problem that the splash screen always on display when I create new activity [image]

It just cover the whole activity layout, is there anyway to remove it? I'm new to Android. I dont know how to search this problem on Google. Please help.

Comment: You have to programmatically set the timings of splash screen using handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) is the best tutorial for splash screens

create a drawable background_splash

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</item>
```

add theme

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

add to you manifiest

```
<activity
android:name=".SplashActivity"
android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

add splash activity that forwards to your main activity

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace your main application with splash theme. So Please separate your main application theme and your splash theme.

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

// Splash Theme

```
     <style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
  </style>
```

[Change Theme in XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTYYc.png)